# The output of nvidia-smi stopped and I could not back to the console

Tags: linux, putty

I used Putty to link with Linux Server. When I write down the command "nvidia-smi", the output stopped in the halfway. Things are like the [following picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV0cY.png).

When the output stopped, I could not do anything meaningful. The input from my keyboard doesn't work any more.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: The same situation happed when I write the comman "w".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).